# How to compute the quotient and localization of the monoid algebra $kG$ for a field $k$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, toric-varieties, localization

I am given that $k$ is a field and $G$ is the monoid consisting of all monomials
$X^iY^j$, where $j$ is between $0$ and $3i$.
I am trying to compute the quotient of the monoid algebra $kG$ by the ideal generated by
$X$ and the localization of $kG$ at the element $X$.
I thought the quotient ring is isomorphic to $k$, since all monomials $X^iY^j$ where $i$ is positive collapse to zero in the quotient.
Is this correct?
How could I compute the localization of $kG$ at the element $X$?
I was also thinking that we could visualize the ring $kG$ using the cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by $e_1$ and $e_1+3e_2$.
Maybe this visualization would be helpful?
Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ commute in your monoid?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Yes, X and Y commute in the monoid G.

Comment: Must $j$ be a multiple of $3$?  That is, is $G$ supposed to be the monoid generated by the submonoid of the free commutative monoid on two generators generated by (1,0) and (1,3)?  I think you might want to be more careful with your notation here because $XY^3$ is not a multiple of $X$ in this monoid.  Your choice of using the embedding into the polynomial ring on X,Y  makes things confusing.

Comment: It seems to me that $(1,0)$, $(1,3)$ freely generate a free commutative monoid on two generators because you can check the second coordinate to know how many $(1,3)$'s were used.  In that case $KG/(X)$ is just a polynomial ring in one variable.  Note you should really not use G for a monoid but rather M.  Similarly, if you view $KG$ as a polynomial ring in two variables one variable corresponding to $(1,0)$ and the other to $(1,3)$, then the localization question becomes much easier.

Comment: Hello Benjamin. Thank you very much for your help and comments. J is only assumed to be between 0 and 3 times of I. So J need not be a multiple of 3.

Comment: That is different than generating with e1 and e1+3e2.  That's why I was confused

Comment: Thanks for telling me this information.